# How does respec cost scale/decay?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've heard rumors that respec cost if done too often will creep up to 100g + per respec and that the cost may decay if you don't do a respec for a long time.

What's the story on respec costs (cap if any)  and decay?

Answer (score 1):

The system was changed, it used to be 1g, 5g, 10g, 25g, 50g maximum (I think), then decayed 5g a month to a minimum of 10g.

Now with the new patch, the respec cost is fixed to your level. At level 80, the respec cost is always 52g.

Comment: It was definitely 50g maximum.  I wasn't aware that it's changed.  That's unfortunate, because most of my 80s were still sitting on a 1g or 5g respec fee.

Comment: Ya I was sure about the maximum, just not the scale to get there. But ya same with me, the change came with 4.0.3.

Comment: I respecced my level 71(72?) Paladin for the first time - was disappointed it cost 18g :(  Oh well.

Comment: This must have changed again... I just respec'd an 80 warlock and it was more like 26g... perhaps the cap is 52g.

Comment: I've seen both the 52G and 26G respec costs.  I don't remember exactly, but it may be that it's different for each of your dual-specs.  i.e. 52G for mainspec, 26G for 2nd spec.